# count on bar graph jqflot

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've created a bar graph using jq flot. I need to add the item count on the top of each bar graph columns. How can I achieve this using jqflot?[image]

Answer (score 0):

After hours of google i found this flot plugins github https://github.com/winne27/flot-valuelabels